# What is the diff between this two arrow functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Basically, I don't understand why the second arrow function works, and first doesn't.

```
    //this one doesnt
    this.setState = () => {
            text: e.target.value,
        };
  
    //this one works
    this.setState(() => ({
            text: e.target.value,
        }));
```

Comment: The first one *replaces* the default `setState` with an unrelated function, meaning you'll never set state in that component again. The second one *calls* `setState` using the function argument (but unnecessarily, since it's not using the function's arguments supplied by React).

Comment: `=` is assignment. This is not a comparison of two function calls, but a comparison between an assignment and a function call.

Comment: Okey! That makes perfect sense! Thank you for answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one assigns the arrow function to this.setState and since there is an existing function called setState on **this**, it'll be overwritten by your arrow function.

The second one passes the arrow function as an argument to setState and setState will call the function you just passed at some point in its execution.

You can refer to the documentation to get a better idea of what setState does.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Answer (score 2):

The first one is an **assignment** the second one performs **execution**.